# How to access the "Software Update Preferences" GUI on a RHEL 7 server?

Tags: rhel, yum, upgrade, gui, software-updates

I have numerous RHEL 6 servers and we configure automatic updates using the "Software Update Preferences" GUI, however I cannot locate the same GUI on a newer RHEL 7 server.

This is the GUI that I am looking to access. I am not interested in other tools like `yum-cron` etc. I wish to access this GUI, same as we've always done.

Is there some way to make it appear, since it does not seem to be present in the menus?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a gui, but yum-cron will do what you want I think

```
 yum install yum-cron
```

The default config follows and changing apply-updates to yes  should do what you want

## /etc/yum/yum-cron.conf

```
#  What kind of update to use:
# default                            = yum upgrade
# security                           = yum --security upgrade
# security-severity:Critical         = yum --sec-severity=Critical upgrade
# minimal                            = yum --bugfix upgrade-minimal
# minimal-security                   = yum --security upgrade-minimal
# minimal-security-severity:Critical =  --sec-severity=Critical upgrade-minimal
update_cmd = default

# Whether a message should be emitted when updates are available,
# were downloaded, or applied.
update_messages = yes

# Whether updates should be downloaded when they are available.
download_updates = yes

# Whether updates should be applied when they are available.  Note
# that download_updates must also be yes for the update to be applied.
apply_updates = no

# Maximum amount of time to randomly sleep, in minutes.  The program
# will sleep for a random amount of time between 0 and random_sleep
# minutes before running.  This is useful for e.g. staggering the
# times that multiple systems will access update servers.  If
# random_sleep is 0 or negative, the program will run immediately.
# 6*60 = 360
random_sleep = 360
```

Comment: unfortunately, the question specifically delines `yum-cron`